# Remove orphaned media files in WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have many orphaned files in `Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media`. Although many images and videos have been removed from chats and are no longer visible within WhatsApp (neither in the chat info screens nor under `Settings/Storage and data/Manage storage`), the files still consume space and are visible in the gallery app.

Interesting fact: **Manage storage** states that WhatsApp is using 15 GB, but does not reveal any more details. All chats are very small.

How can I delete the orphans permanently without losing all the other media files from important chats? Is there some way to tell from the directory structure which files belong to which chat and remove them manually?

Comment: I dont see how you know they are orphans.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. "*Manage storage states that WhatsApp is using 15 GB*" I believe you should be able to tap that menu to see the breakdown of how WhatsApp counts its storage usage.